# Show image in gallery along with others in same directory

Tags: android

My app shows all the images(as thumbnails in grid) of a specific folder and when user clicks on a thumbnail it shows in gallery. All works good but I want that when user slide left or right it should show other images in that directory(usual gallery behaviour). But now, it just shows only one image that was opened by the app.

Here is the code I use :

```
public File OpenFile(String filePath) {     
        File file = new File(filePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);          
        intent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, FILEOPEN);
        return file;        
}
```

Edit: 
Min Sdk 1.6

Comment: can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check this library for your problem. i have used this library to switch images from gridview to viewPager..

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: That library need Android 2.0+, but I need for 1.6. Thanks. Now I have added that in question.

Comment: Why is 1.6 a requirement?  1.6 is basically like supporting Windows 3.1-  1.6 is less than .1% of all phones using the play store.  Its not worth the extra effort of supporting.